# Что значит manifest в гугл консоль панели разработчика

Tags: javascript, frontend, google-console

Что значит manifest в гугл консоли в панели разработчика?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скорее всего вот это https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы разрабатываете PWA, то вам нужен manifest-файл в формате JSON, в котором указаны метаданные о вашем приложении. В нем можно указать, к примеру иконки, которые будут показываться на рабочем столе или заголовок. Браузер сам решает, как обрабатывать этот файл, и некоторые поля могут быть не использованы(в зависимости от платформы, браузера и его версии). Больше о PWA и manifest [здесь](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp?hl=ru)